# How do I choose the correct airfoil for my UAV project?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am not able to decide which airfoil to choose for my UAV project as I am confused. I need to lift at least 10kg of extra payload excluding the weight of the fuselage. I can afford a wingspan of 3m with a cruising speed of at least 70kmph. Also I would like to know if there is any software or application to decide the airfoil for me?

Comment: You need to solve $L=1/2 C_L \rho V^2 A$. First [determine the lift coefficient required for your airfoil](https://www.ajdesigner.com/phpwinglift/wing_lift_equation_force.php) based on required lift, speed and area, then select the airfoil with this $C_L$. You know you need a lift force of $10kg \times 9.81 ms^{-2} = 98 N$ for the payload.

Comment: You'll need the weight of the entire aircraft and fuel load to be determined with some sort of accuracy beforehand, not just your payload. Then you can find a $C_L$ range that would work. From there you can optimize the $C_D$ and $Re$ of the airfoil to suit your performance needs.

Comment: I found few great websites for choosing the right airfoil, so pick what shape of airfoil you need, to to this website... http://www.airfieldmodels.com/information_source/math_and_science_of_model_aircraft/rc_aircraft_design/plotting_airfoils/about_airfoils.htm - To choose the right airfoil from a large database, go here... airfoiltools.com

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of aircraft aerodynamic design. One method is through using known airfoils (for wing and tail surfaces) and deciding other geometric parameters iteratively while meeting certain criteria for performance, stability, control, aeroelasticity, manufacturibility, etc.

The other method is deciding roughly on the size and then attempting to come up with an airfoil shape, that (again) meets certain criteria. This second sort of design process is named *inverse design*. Where you try to get a desired *Pressure distribution* through computational iterations.

There are open source and free software as well as commercial options for both methods. Search terms: Airfoil design.

Any general RC aircraft design guideline and relevant spreadsheets will speed up the learning process. Search terms: RC aircraft design guide.

For detail information about the theory and practice; please refer to aircraft aerodynamic design textbooks.

Hope this answer sheds some light onto this wonderful and exciting topic. Feel free to shoot specific questions.